# Insert R code in different colour

Tags: r, colors, rstudio

This could be a straightforward question but I have not been able to sort this out.

I have an R script that someone sent me with some code in it. I want to add additional code. However, I want my code to appear in different colour so that the person can see which code have I inserted.

Is it possible to do that in R studio? I am using R studio which already uses different colours for text, library and code.

Thanks

Comment: Did you search the RStudio website?  Possibly an add-in?

Comment: with git you can commit his work then modify and check the difference  https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532077-Version-Control-with-Git-and-SVN

Comment: #versionControl

Comment: Those color aren't stored in the code files. The code is just plain text. The IDE colors them based on where the source comes from. You typically cannot add formatting (bold, italic, colors) to code that differs from the standard rules in they way you can a Word document.

Comment: Okay. This makes sense. Thanks. I will have to try what brunel suggested